# Two mutable pointers

Tags: rust, reference, mutability

While studying `async_std` I have come across the following idiom in Rust

```
let (reader, writer) = &mut (&stream, &stream);
```

Which makes both `reader` and `writer` mutable pointers to `stream`. How does it work?
Doesn't Rust stop you from having two or more mutable pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which makes both `reader` and `writer` mutable pointers to `stream`.

It doesn't. This is a mutable reference to a tuple which contains *immutable* references to `stream`. There is no possibility of using this to mutate the original `stream`, all you can do is mutate the tuple by swapping a reference to a completely different stream.

You can use methods of `Read` and `Write` on these because `&TcpStream` implements `Read` and `Write`. In that expression, the type of `reader` and `writer` is `&mut &TcpStream`, ***not*** `&mut TcpStream`.

Note that `Read` and `Write` are not implemented for references to all types that implement them. For example `Write` is implemented for `Cursor<Vec<u8>>` but it is ***not*** implemented for `&Cursor<Vec<u8>>`. This implementation would be unsound because it would allow the same bit of memory to be accessed via two different mutable references.

The trait methods mostly take `&mut self` so that ***if*** it is unsafe to have multiple readers or writers on the same reader or writer, it can be implemented soundly and the Rust type system will take care of making sure that there is only one. But this would be too restrictive for `TcpStream`, since it's ok to have multiple readers and writers.

Rather than duplicating code by adding another more permissive trait `async_std` implements `Read` and `Write` for immutable references in cases where it is sound to do so. The pattern you've seen is a kind of "trick" that makes this design work.

Comment: But I'm able to use `writer` later in a mutable fashion: `writer.write_all(str.as_bytes()).await?;` write_all requires a mutable reference, right?

Comment: `Write` is implemented for `&TcpStream`. It's completely ok to take a mutable reference to an immutable one.